# How can i customize grand totals in tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

I am having a table with percentage in cells. i am calling R and calculating sigma for each cell. Now i want row and column grand totals of the sigma that is calculated.
I referred some articles on how to customize grand totals but even that did not help.could it be because i am calculating the cell value using R.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking on Analysis > Totals > Show Row Grand totals?

Answer (score 0):

1) Click on Analysis->Create Calculated Field… The Calculated Field dialog will open.

2) Make the name “Fake GT Header” (without the quotes)

3) Make the fomula “Grand Total” (with the quotes)

4) Click OK to save the calculated field. Tableau will automatically make it a Dimension in the Data window.

5) Drag the “Fake GT Header” field from the Dimensions area to the Rows Shelf.

Does that answer your question?